# Get contents of Google Drive spreadsheet in CSV format

Tags: node.js, request, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the file contents of a Google Drive Spreadsheet via node.js. I am using the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) to get the `access_token` and the [node-google-drive](https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-google-drive) module to get the `file_id`.

```
"https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+file_id+"&exportFormat=csv&gid=0"
```

When I'm logged into the Google Drive and I go to that URL above it downloads the spreadsheet in CSV format. When I try to go to that URL in incognito it shows a login page, which is the same page I'm getting in the body of my request within node.js.

```
request({
    "method":"get",
    "url": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export",
    "qs":{
        "key": key,
        "exportFormat": "csv",
        "gid": 0
    },
    "headers":{
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    }
}, function(err, response, body){
    console.log(response);
});
```

I've tried to send a `Authorization` header, but I'm still getting an HTML response. Containing `Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.`

Comment: Try inspecting the header the browser sends when you're logged in and visiting that page and comparing those with with what request sends. Then try eliminating the differences one by one. At some point it should probably start working. I don't know anything about this particular API, but I wouldn't be surprised that it works if you send the login cookie along.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but it didn't work.

Comment: Any leads on this? I'm trying to do the same. Thanks!

Comment: I had the wrong google drive api "scope" and that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: @ThomasReggi Would you mind documenting what you did as an answer? I'm curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this: https://github.com/jpillora/node-edit-google-spreadsheet

Example

```
var Spreadsheet = require('edit-google-spreadsheet');

Spreadsheet.create({
  debug: true,
  username: [GOOGLE USERNAME],
  password: [PASSWORD],
  spreadsheetName: 'node-edit-spreadsheet',
  worksheetName: 'Sheet1',
  spreadsheetId: '[DOC ID]',
  callback: run
});

function run(err, spreadsheet) {
  if(err) throw err;
  //receive all cells
  spreadsheet.receive(function(err, rows, info) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Found rows:", rows);
    console.log("With info:", info);
  });
}
```

Regards,

/t